# How to know if it's safe to run newer software versions on servers than provided by Ubuntu's default repository?

Tags: server, php, security, nginx

I would like to set up a public web server and have to decide which versions of Nginx, PHP, etc to use. The versions Ubuntu's default repository provides are a bit outdated (e.g. it provides PHP 7.0 but the newest version is already 7.3). I'm afraid that I'm missing out in terms of performance and security, if I don't use the newest versions.

So is there a way to know if it's safe to run newer software versions on servers than provided by Ubuntu's default repository? Or is there any kind of rule-of-thumb approach?

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: The Ubuntu repos may have older software, but later security-fixes are back-ported to them (esp. 'main' repo software).  The default Ubuntu repositories (esp. 'main') are updated (*with back-ported security fixes*) by Canonical for the given 5 years (longer if you use extended or ESM); where as other sources may not have set lengths of support and often require you to watch & switch when they change.  General rules such as this won't cover every circumstance (*and I've limited my comment to the easier 'main' repo*).

Comment: PHP 7.0 is in Ubuntu 16.04. The three-year-old release has three-year-old software (suitably patched for security fixes). Newer releases of Ubuntu have newer software. Ubuntu 18.04, for example, has PHP 7.2.